# moving Drupal 6 site - get blank white page

Tags: drupal, transfer, failed-installation, bootstrapping

I moved Drupal from one Linux server to another by copying files to PC then back to new server. I made changes to settings.php to reflect new database name.  I got PHPmyADMIN working, so I know database and server are running.

When I run index.php, I get white screen. However in index.php when I echo out menu_execute_active_handler(), I get some part of my home page without menus. I think that this means that I am getting through bootstrap but failing somewhere else.  Any ideas?

**index.php**

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$return = menu_execute_active_handler();


echo $return ;
```

Comment: Do you have [`display_errors = on`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in `php.ini` ?

Comment: beauty! Call to undefined function date_format() in /var/www/html/sites/default/modules/contributed/date/date_api.module on line 2500

Comment: Guess I better leave an answer then :)

Comment: I remember we had this problem before. We are at PHP Version 5.1.6. I think we had to downgrade last time.

Comment: you win! now to remember how to downgrade PHP :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on in your `php.ini` file.

Your new server probably has them disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your index.php to see the error

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);